# TYPO3 ckeditor add bootstrap class for tables

Tags: ckeditor, typo3

I try to add the classes `"table"` and `"table-striped"` via yaml-File to the ckeditor in TYPO3 8.
With other block-tags or inline-tags there is no problem, but with tables there ist still the class `"contenttable"` - and only this class, I can't add other classes.
I tried this:

```
{ name: "Table", element: ['table','p'], attributes: { 'class': 'table' }}

{ name: "Table-Striped", element: ['table','p'], attributes: { 'class': 'table-striped' }}
```

for p it is ok (with no sense), but not for the table.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and found a workaround.
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/81676

**YAML**

```
editor:
config:
    stylesSet:
        - { name: "Table borderless", element: "table", attributes: { 'class': 'contenttable contenttable--borderless' } }
```

**TypoScript**

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.externalBlocks.table.stdWrap.HTMLparser.tags.table.fixAttrib.class.list := addToList(contenttable, contenttable--borderless)
```